# Change color to WMS tile polygon in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, style

I am a beginner in working with WMS services. In OpenLayers I retrieved a file ([EEZ 200 NM](https://data.apps.fao.org/catalog/dataset/flanders-marine-institute-vliz-geoserver-wms-service-exclusive-economic-zone-200-nm)) from GeoServer to which I would like to change the fill color. Is that anyway possible from OpenLayers?

```
    const source_eez_WMS = new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'https://geo.vliz.be/geoserver/MarineRegions/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities',
      params: {
        'FORMAT': 'image/png', 
         tiled: true,
         STYLES: '',
         LAYERS: 'eez'
    
      },
      serverType:'geoserver',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    });
    const layer_eez_WMS = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: source_eez_WMS,
        visible:true
     });
```

Comment: You'd need to send an updated style, using the the SLD or SLD_BODY parameters to the service.  The service would change the style and send back an updated image

Comment: Or you could use the WFS and get the vector data and style it in your client

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will study how to use SLD and try to apply it, as WFS is not feasible (the file is way too big)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for [try this](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html)